# Set with empty interior in $L^1([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F_n :=\{f \in L^1([0,1]) :\int \limits_{0}^1|f|^2d\mu ≤ n\}$.

Mainly, I am struggling to show $F_n$ is closed and has an empty interior in $L^1([0,1])$, for all $n ≥ 1$. 
Further, it think that $L^2([0,1])$ can be represented as a countable union of $F_n$, is this right?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? That $F_n$ is closed? That it has empty interior? Where precisely does the struggle commence? What have you tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you can prove the more general result that If $1\le p<q<\infty$ then $L^q([0,1])$ is first category in $L^p([0,1]).$

Let's prove the result. So, define $A_n = \{f \in L^p([0,1]) \ | \ \|f\|_q^q \le n\}$. To show that $A_n$ is closed, take a sequence $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A_n$ such that $\|f_k -f\|_p \to 0$. We want to show that this implies $f \in A_n$. First, we note that $\|f_k -f \|_p \to 0$ implies that there is a subsequence $f_{k_j}$ which converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$. Then by Fatou's lemma: 
$$\int_0^1 |f|^q = \int_0^1 \liminf_{j} |f_{k_j}|^q \le \liminf_j \int |f_{k_j}|^q \le n.$$
Hence $A_n$ is closed.

To see that $A_n$ has empty interior, first we show that it is convex. So, take any $f, g \in A_n$. Then $\|f\|_q \le n^{1/q}$ and likewise $\|g\|_q \le n^{1/q}$. Then 
$$\|tf + (1-t)g\|_q \le t\|f\|_q + (1-t)\|g\|_q \le tn^{1/q} + (1-t)n^{1/q} = n^{1/q}$$
and so the line parametrized by $tf + (1-t)g, 0\le t \le 1$ is contained in $A_n$. Hence $A_n$ is convex.

In what follows, all the balls are taken relative to the $L^p$ norm. Suppose that $A_n$ didn't have empty interior (in the $L^p$ norm), so it contains some ball around some $f$, that is, $A_n \supset B_r(f) = \{g \in L^p([0,1]) \ | \ \|f-g\|_p <r\}$. It follows immediately that $B_r(-f) \subset A_n$, since $|-g|= |g|$ (which is relevant when looking at the $L^p$ norm of functions). But since $A_n$ is convex, every function on the "line" between $g$ and $-g$ is contained in $A_n$ for every $g \in B_r(f)$. Hence $B_r(0) \subset A_n$. Now, if $h \in L^p([0,1])$ then $h$ is some scalar multiple of a function in $B_r(0)$. Then $h = cg$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g \in B_r(0)$. Thus $h \in A_n$, since $\|h\|_q^q = |c|^q\|g\|_q^q <\infty$, as $g \in A_n$. So then $h \in L^q([0,1])$. Since $h$ was an arbitrary $L^p$ function, this says that $L^p([0,1]) \subset L^q([0,1])$. Since we know that $L^q([0,1]) \subset L^p([0,1])$, we can conclude that $ L^p([0,1]) = L^q([0,1])$. But we immediately see this to be a contradiction, since we can take $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{x^{1/q}}$. Then 
$$\int_0^1 |f^p| = \int_0^1 x^{-p/q} \ dx = \frac{1}{1-p/q} x^{1-p/q}\biggm|_0^1 <\infty$$
 since $\displaystyle \frac pq<1$. But
$$\int_0^1 |f|^q = \int_0^1 \frac1x\ dx$$
diverges. So then $L^p([0,1]) \neq L^q([0,1])$, and hence our assumption that $A_n$ did not have an empty interior leads to a contradiction.

So $A_n$ is closed and has empty interior, which says that it is nowhere dense. We may conclude by noting that $L^q([0,1]) = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$, and since each $A_n$ is nowhere dense (relative to the $L^p$ norm) in $L^p([0,1])$, we have that $L^q([0,1]) $ is first category in $L^p([0,1])$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence in $F_n$ and $f_k\to f$ in $L^1$. By passing to a subsequence if necessary, we have that $f_k\to f$ almost everywhere, and so by Fatou's lemma $\int|f|^2\le\liminf_{k\to\infty}\int|f_k|^2$, i.e. $f\in F_n$. Hence $F_n$ is closed.

Now observe that $F_n\subset L^2([0,1])$ which is a (proper) subspace of $L^1([0,1])$. For any normed vector space $X$, no proper subspace has non-empty interior. Indeed, suppose $Y\subseteq X$ is a subspace with non-empty interior. Then there exists $x_0\in Y$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset Y$. If $x\in X$, then $z=x_0+\frac\epsilon2\frac{x}{\|x\|}\in B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset Y$. Since $Y$ is a subspace, this implies $x=\frac{2}{\epsilon\|x\|}(z-x_0)\in Y$, completing the proof.

Comment: It seems that $F_{n}$ is not a subspace?

Comment: No, but $L^2([0,1])$ is.

Comment: I misunderstood that, and yes, essentially you are proving that $L^{2}$ cannot have nonempty interior (in $L^{1}$), then neither $F_{n}$, brilliant.