# Prove $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ has empty interior both in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I suppose it has interior, so we can find an open ball of radius epsilon in $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and so that ball is contained in both the sets, so we can write:
$$B_\varepsilon=\{u(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R}):||u(x)||_{L^1}<\varepsilon\}=\{u(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):||u(x)||_{L^2}<\varepsilon\}$$
But now I can't find the contradiction. I tried to compute the norms but I can't end with a contradiction. I can't find it at all. I don't know if this is the right way.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560595/set-with-empty-interior-in-l10-1. It is not exactly your question, but it is close and can be adapted I think.

Comment: Interior where? Please edit the question so that it makes sense.

Comment: @zwim Thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is an interior point in $L^{2}$. Consider $f+\frac 1 {nx} I_{x>1}$. Show that this sequence converges to $f$ in $L^{2}$ and none of these functions are in $L^{1}$. This proves that interior in $L^{2}$ is empty. For interior in $L^{1}$ consider $f+\frac 1 {n\sqrt x} I_{0<x<1}$.

Comment: Nice, I'm trying to understand all the things you put here. If I'll have other doubts I'll write here. Thanks.

Comment: @jameswatt Most welcome I will try to clear all your doubts.

Comment: I think that from your answer it follows that the intersection has empty interior. Why you use those counter example to prove this? I mean you find a sequence of convergent functions in $L^2$ and not in $L^1$, but how this is linked to the fact of finding open balls into a set? (because from the definition of interior we need to find an open ball into a set)

Comment: Moreover, I tried to study the $L^1$ convergence of the first sequence: $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f_n|dx=\int_\mathbb{R}|f+\dfrac{\chi_{(1,+\infty)}}{nx}|dx>\int_1^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{nx}=0$$ so how I can show those functions don't belong to $L^1$?

Comment: @jameswatt Since $f$ is already in $L^{1}$ we cannot have the sum in $L^{1}$ unless the second term is in $L^{1}$. But $\frac 1 {nx} I_{x>1}$ is not in $L^{1}$ for any $n$. BTW $\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 x dx=\infty$, not zero.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{nx}\,dx = 0$

Comment: @soundwave $\lim \infty$ is not $0$. Besides, there was no limit; we had to just compute the integral for fixed $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ah ok thanks

Comment: Could you explain the idea of the resolution? Because I can't understand why you take $f\in L^2$ and a sequence not in $L^2$. What this has in common to the fact of finding an open ball inside $L^1\cap L^2$?

Comment: Please, could you check if my solution corresponds to yours? https://i.imgur.com/jix20bo.png

Comment: @jameswatt You have used the inequality $|a+b| >|b|$ which is false. Your proof is almost same as mine but you have made a mistake in the proof.

Comment: I ended up with this: https://i.imgur.com/TZqF6ob.png I think it's correct now.